# How to track 3-D object through vuforia?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, augmented-reality

I have been trying to detect 3-D object by using **Vuforia SDK** in my Augment reality app. I have created cuboid tracker and given images to all the faces while creating marker. But while detecting, its detecting front face only after lots of trying. Help in any means will be very useful.

My XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QCARConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="qcar_config.xsd">
    <Tracking>
        <ImageTarget size="320 220" name="Phone.Top"/>
        <ImageTarget size="320 220" name="Phone.Bottom"/>
        <ImageTarget size="320 220" name="Phone.Back"/>
        <ImageTarget size="320 220" name="Phone.Front"/>
        <ImageTarget size="220 220" name="Phone.Right"/>
        <ImageTarget size="220 220" name="Phone.Left"/>
        <MultiTarget name="Phone">
            <Part name="Phone.Front" translation="0 0 110" rotation="AD: 1 0 0 0"/>
            <Part name="Phone.Back" translation="0 0 -110" rotation="AD: 0 1 0 180"/>
            <Part name="Phone.Left" translation="-160 0 0" rotation="AD: 0 1 0 -90"/>
            <Part name="Phone.Right" translation="160 0 0" rotation="AD: 0 1 0 90"/>
            <Part name="Phone.Top" translation="0 110 0" rotation="AD: 1 0 0 -90"/>
            <Part name="Phone.Bottom" translation="0 -110 0" rotation="AD: 1 0 0 90"/>
        </MultiTarget>
    </Tracking>
</QCARConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the metaio SDK which is supporting both 3D object tracking and SLAM. For more information please check out www.metaio.com/products/SDK

Cheers, Daniel

Comment: Hey Daniel! Can we detect two similar 3-D objects but different in color with  Metaio SDK?

Comment: Metaio sdk support is off now. How can we detect 3-d object now except metaio ?